# Link to Repo In TeamCity Build

Tags: teamcity, bitbucket

Is there a way to get a link to a bitbucket hosted repo to show up in a TeamCity build? The build knows which VCS root the commit came from as well as the commit hash, I just can't find a way to get that to display as a clickable link in the build.

Comment: Where abouts in the build do you want it to appear? In the build log? In the build config name?

Comment: @Castrohenge anywhere would be fine. Maybe in the Overview page?

Answer (score 1):

You can use repo URL as VCS root's name and it will be visible on Changes tab of the build.

But more general, why would you need the link to bitbucket? There is a perfect change log and diff-viewer right inside TeamCity web UI.

Comment: Sometimes TeamCity doesn't pull the repo like I expect and commits get squashed: youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-39033

Answer (score 0):

With some finangling, you can set up an external change viewer. Documentation is here: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/External+Changes+Viewer

Unfortunately, you'll need to use the "build-specific" syntax as there's no project/repo-agnostic URL that you can feed to bitbucket. Here's an example:

`ProjectName_BuildName.changeSetUrl=https://bitbucket.example.com/projects/MYPROJECT/repos/my-repo/commits/${changeSetDisplayRevision}`

`ProjectName_Buildname` is really the "Build configuration ID" that you set (or use the suggestion).